# Smart way to load a local python module with a class instance?

Tags: python, class, module

What is a smart way to load a local python file with a python class instance so that all variables defined in that python file gets added to the class's attributes?

Comment: Have you tried using an `import` statement?

Comment: Can you suggest its usage, meaning I would want to do a `from something import *` within a class but that is disallowed, also would not assign the variables to the class attributes, right?

Comment: Are you trying to load some initialization values?

Comment: Any sort of values, in this case, some settings for another program..

Comment: Why are you defining the variables separately from the class in the first place?

Comment: In that case, write some `config file` using `yaml`, `toml`, or plain text, read it, parse it, and assign the values to your instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a file `vars.py` containing:

```
x = 2
y = 'fish'
for i in range(4):
    x = x * 3
```

Then load `x` and `y` into a class in 2 ways:

### Using `__import__()`

Note: This will stuff all the globals from your module into the class. A lot of junk. Also the imported name has to be a package, not just a single file.

```
class DangerZone:
    def load_attrs(self, fn):
        _vars = __import__(fn)
        for attr_name, attr_val in _vars.items():
            self.__dict__[attr_name] = attr_val
```

### Using `exec()`

Ok this is dangerous (using `exec()` to run arbitrary code from outside), but here goes.

```
class DangerZone:
    def load_attrs(self, fn):
        _globals = {}
        _locals = {}
        exec(open(fn).read(), _globals, _locals)
        for attr_name, attr_val in _locals.items():
            self.__dict__[attr_name] = attr_val
```

### Result:

```
dz = DangerZone()
dz.load_attrs('vars.py')
print(dz.x, dz.y)
```

Prints:

```
162 fish
```

Comment: Why are you reimplementing `import vars`?

Comment: Just to separate globals and locals really. If you don't mind that, then you can instead of `exec()` use `_vars = __import(fn)` and then copy attributes from `_vars` to the class `__dict__`

Comment: Updated the answer to include dynamic import with `__import__()`

Comment: You might want to read about `importlib`; using `__import__` directly should not be necessary.